# Android application crashes when populating spinner

Tags: android, crash, spinner

I'm trying to populate the spinner, but the application crashes on spiner.setAdapter(adapter)...

```
final Context c=this;
ArrayList<CountryItem> countriesArray = GetCountries1();
ArrayAdapter<CountryItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CountryItem>(
    c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesArray); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
final Spinner spiner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spiner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I can't find any errors here, and eclipse debug mode does not show anything usefull...
Here is the example from google...is it so much different than my code?

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error do you get?

Did you check if the `countriesArray` has elements or if it is empty?

Is it working when you use, e.g., a simple string array? If yes, then the problem lies with the `CountryItem` objects.

Other than that, the only difference I see is that you pass the context as a `final` variable, but I don't know if this causes the error. Try to pass just `this` and see if it works.

Comment: This question is more than one year old... I didn't know how to use stack overflow that time... :) so I'm accepting this answer now... If I remember right it was the context variable that was causing the problem..